# in go lang, why this is 7 ? assert(5^2 == 7)

Tags: go

in go lang, why this is 7 ?

`assert(5^2 == 7)`

so strange.
I tried to google it. but google does not work well with special characters.
Thanks.

Comment: In binary, `101` xor'd with `010` is `111`.

Comment: This is not `go` specific `^` is `XOR` operator in most programming languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `^` operator is the XOR (exclusive OR), applied bitwise if operands are numbers.

```
5 = 101b // in binary, but Go doesn't have binary literals
2 = 010b
XOR:
7 = 111b
```

Answer (score 7):

It is an [Arithmetic operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators):

```
^    bitwise XOR            integers
```

You can see it on this [Bitwise Calculator](http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/?data_type=10&number1=5&number2=2&operator=XOR)

```
Result in binary    111
```

Answer (score 2):

As others already described, ^ is an operator for XOR. If you want to calculate the square of 5, you can use math.Pow() function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("square of 5 = %f\n", math.Pow(5,2))
}
```